# How to merge exists data with new data?

Tags: php, laravel

**Method 1 :** Here I wrote the code for insert booking seat data into the database

**Problem :** When I book new seat it will creating new row so I'm getting duplicate rows so I tried method 2

Method 1 code :

```
$booking = new Bookings();
        $booking->users_id = 4;
        $booking->schedules_id = $schedules_id;
        $booking->buses_id = $buses_id;
        $booking->routes_id = $routes_id;
        $booking->seat = implode(',', $seat);
        $booking->price = $request->price;
        $booking->profile = 'pending';
```

**Method 2 :** Here checking `schedules_id` equal to exists `schedules_id` then update seat and other data's

**Problem :** Insert new data updating old data

Method 2 code :

```
$booking = Bookings::updateOrCreate(
    ['schedules_id' => $schedules_id], // match the row based on this array
    [ // update this columns
        'buses_id' => $buses_id,
        'routes_id' => $routes_id,
        'seat' => json_encode($seat),
        'price' => $request->price,
        'profile' => 'pending',
    ]

);
```

// I don't know this is logically correct or wrong

**My idea :** Here I'm retrieving old data and storing into one variable then merging old data and new data into one column

**Problem :** Getting error.

My idea code :

```
$extSeat = DB::table('bookings')->select('seat')->get();
        $booking = Bookings::updateOrCreate(
           ['schedules_id' => $schedules_id],
           [ // update this columns
              'buses_id' => $buses_id,
              'routes_id' => $routes_id,
              'seat' => implode(",", array_merge($seat,$extSeat)),
              'price' => $request->price,
              'profile' => 'pending',
           ]);
```

what i actually need ? : i need merge exists data with new data without updating.

Old data look like `A1,B1`
 
when insert new data like `C1` 

 i need data like this `A1,B1,C1`

I hope I explain clear enough. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why not use a relation on the seat-field?

Comment: @stUrb sir can u please explain clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this is a correct logic or not but works for me, any other suggestions are welcome.

```
    $extSeat = DB::table('bookings')->select('seat')->first();
    $extSeat = explode(",", $extSeat->seat);
    $booking = Bookings::updateOrCreate(
       ['schedules_id' => $schedules_id],
       [ // update this columns
          'buses_id' => $buses_id,
          'routes_id' => $routes_id,
          'seat' => implode(",", array_merge($seat,$extSeat )),
          'price' => $request->price,
          'profile' => 'pending',
       ]);
```